# How to Validate OpenID Connect Access Token generated by Azure AD v2 in ASP.NET core WEB API?

Tags: c#, angular, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect

How to Validate OpenID Connect Access Token generated by Azure AD (v2!!!) in ASP.NET core WEB API?

The Scenario is:

I have an Angular 8 Client Application which is getting an OpenID Connect access Token after Login.
The Client can call the API along with the Access Token. 
But Question is, How should I validate that Token in ASP.NET core API?

With this code I get an Authorize Error without any descriptions.

```
  services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
             .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                });
        });
```

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: AzureADJwtBearer was challenged.

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "localhost",
"TenantId": "myTenantId",
"ClientId": "myClientId"
```

},

Comment: please verify the configuration file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Domain` is not `localhost` . You need specify the TenantId only if you want to accept access tokens from a single tenant . Otherwise, you can leave them set to `common`:

```
This value can be:
- A GUID (Tenant ID = Directory ID)
- 'common' (any organization and personal accounts)
- 'organizations' (any organization)
- 'consumers' (Microsoft personal accounts)
```

And you should change to use the Microsoft identity platform endpoint(Azure AD V2.0 endpoint) by adding this code to the `Startup.cs` file:

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    // This is a Microsoft identity platform web API.
    options.Authority += "/v2.0";

    .....
});
```

You can click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration) for detail explanation and code sample .

Comment: Super! Thank you for your help. It works now. Is it possible to control the authentication only in ASP.NET core backend and not in Angular side? If not. Can I use the authorization code flow and not the imlicit flow in my SPA Client?

Comment: >Is it possible to control the authentication only in ASP.NET core backend and not in Angular side? Web api doesn't control the authentication . > Can I use the authorization code flow and not the imlicit flow in my SPA Client? Code flow needs to send post request to azure ad token endpoint with client secret , which is not reliable/security in a spa client .

Comment: Thank you for your infos. I mean the code PKCE. It does support with Azure AD?

Comment: Refer to : https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce-in-azure-ad-d4a0db31e873