# "Authorization failed. AuthenticationScheme: AzureADJwtBearer was challenged" in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, angular, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect

I'm trying to authenticate my web api using Azure AD.

I'm following this [tutorial](http://mobilefirstcloudfirst.net/2019/08/adding-azure-active-directory-authentication-connect-angular-app-asp-net-core-web-api-using-msal/) and I successfully authenticated using my Angular App.

The problem is, when I put the `Authorize` attribute in my controller, it gives me `401 Unauthorized` error in my angular console and even my post man.

As I view my web api log, it shows like this:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVaeZ.png)

Here's my `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // removed because this doesn't work either
    // services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)           
    //          .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureActiveDirectory", options));

    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureActiveDirectory", options));

    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
                // This is a Microsoft identity platform web API.
        options.Authority += "/v2.0";
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   }

   app.UseRouting();

   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseAuthorization();

   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
   }
}
```

In my `appsettings.json`:

```
"AzureActiveDirectory": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "myorg.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "241234-12ad-1234-1234-123412341234", // sample only
    "ClientId": "8786687-12ad-1234-1234-2341432341" // sample only client id from the webapi in the ad
},
```

In my App Client, here's my `app.module.ts`

```
// MSAL Imports
import {
   MsalModule,
   MsalInterceptor,
   MSAL_CONFIG,
   MSAL_CONFIG_ANGULAR,
   MsalService,
   MsalAngularConfiguration
 } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { Configuration } from 'msal';

// MSAL Configs
export const protectedResourceMap:[string, string[]][]=[['https://localhost:5000/', ['api://WEB-API-CLIENTID/api-access']] ];

const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;

function MSALAngularConfigFactory(): MsalAngularConfiguration {
   return {
     popUp: !isIE,
     consentScopes: [
       "user.read",
       "openid",
       "profile",
       "api://WEBAPI-CLIENT-ID/api-access"
     ],
     unprotectedResources: ["https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/"],
     protectedResourceMap,
     extraQueryParameters: {}
   };
 }

 function MSALConfigFactory(): Configuration {
   return {
     auth: {
       clientId: 'ANGULAR-CLIENT-ID',
       authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT-ID", /// with tenant id
       validateAuthority: true,
       redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
       postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
       navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
     },
     cache: {
       cacheLocation: "localStorage",
       storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
     },
   };
 }

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
      NgHttpLoaderModule.forRoot(),

      FormsModule,
      // msal angular
      MsalModule
   ],
   providers: [
      {
         provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
         useClass: MsalInterceptor,
         multi: true
       },
       {
         provide: MSAL_CONFIG,
         useFactory: MSALConfigFactory
       },
       {
         provide: MSAL_CONFIG_ANGULAR,
         useFactory: MSALAngularConfigFactory
       },
       MsalService
   ],
   bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Other info: I already saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58616371/how-to-validate-openid-connect-access-token-generated-by-azure-ad-v2-in-asp-net) but it doesn't help fix my issue.

I look forward for someone's help.

Comment: How are you acquiring the token in your front-end? Is the tokenVersion 2 in the app manifest? :)

Comment: The tokens are automatically added in the localstorage when you successfully log in in A.D. Because I checked both the "Implicit grant" options for Access Token and Token Id. I also removed the version 2 options in the `startup.cs`, it's still unauthorized.

Comment: Okay, you'll need to inspect the token being sent at https://jwt.ms. Check for example that the audience (aud) matches what your API expects.

Comment: The audience I see in the clientid of my angular app (after I used the jwt.ms) is the clientid of my registered angularapp in my active directory. I also added the clientid of my angular app in the "Authorized client applications (Exposed API menu)" of my webpi AD so it should match together right? But still, I get the "Unauthorized" request.

Comment: @JokerBench The audience should be your webapi application_id, not your angular app id. Please check the value of consentScopes in your angular app. It should be something like api://webapi_client_id/api-access

Comment: Hi @TonyJu, i tried using my api but I get an error message after I successfully login.

Comment: @JokerBench What is the error message?

Comment: @TonyJu After I put the web api client id in my app.module.ts, and successfully put my AD email and password, it returns an error that says, "Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '152123-1234-1234-1234-123412341234124'" (sample digits but this is my web api client id).

Comment: @JokerBench I guess you put it in the wrong place, the client id should still be your angular app client id, you need to check the scope part. Please refer to the angular app part in this article. http://mobilefirstcloudfirst.net/2019/08/adding-azure-active-directory-authentication-connect-angular-app-asp-net-core-web-api-using-msal/

Comment: I also read that blog and followed the steps.

Comment: @JokerBench Can you share your app.module.ts code here?

Comment: HELLO @TonyJu I added my app.module.ts I'm using Angular9

Comment: 1.. you can use the angular app's url don't need to set redirect url in angular , and config that url in  the portal.  2. try to use api://WEB-API-CLIENTID in web api config as ClientId .

Comment: @NanYu I tried these you've mentioned but still, it's unauthorized 401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BearerAuthenticationScheme` The default scheme for Azure Active Directory B2C Bearer. If you are using, `AddAzureADB2CBearer(AuthenticationBuilder, Action<AzureADB2COptions>)` then use `JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme` otherwise, use the default bearer scheme.

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureActiveDirectory", options));
```

Please double check your `clientId` if it's assigned properly to your app. It's only normal to throw a `401 unauthorized` if it's doesn't meet its security requirements.

If you can get the `accessToken`, try if it's a valid access token. Visit this [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/). It should work using Postman if it is valid. make sure you use `Authorization` `Bearer your_accessToken_here`.

You should expect a `200 Ok` in postman. Now, try it on your angular app.